# Prove that f then has the following form: $f(z)=\sum\limits_{k=k_1}^{k_2}a_kz^k$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, proof-writing

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\} \rightarrow C$ holomorphic. Furthermore we assume that c> 0,$k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}, k_1 \leqslant k_2$ exist such that

$|f(z)|\leqslant c(|z|^{k_1}+|z|^{k_2}), z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ (1)

Prove that f then has the following form:
$f(z)=\sum\limits_{k=k_1}^{k_2}a_kz^k$

---

my ideas :

$|f(z)|$ $=|\sum\limits_{k=k_1}^{k_2}a_kz^k$|$\leqslant$ $\sum\limits_{k=k_1}^{k_2}|a_kz^k$|=$\sum\limits_{k=k_1}^{k_2}|a_k||z|^k$

If $ c\geq \sum\limits_{k=k_1}^{k_2}|a_k|$, then $|f(z)|\leqslant c(|z|^{k_1}+|z|^{k_2})$ counts.

So this means if $f(z)$ has the form $\sum\limits_{k=k_1}^{k_2}a_k z^k$, (1) holds.

Now i have still to show that $f(z)$ always has the form of polynom.

Comment: Show that $g=z^{-k_1}f$  is entire and bounded by a polynomial so is a polynomial etc

Comment: thanks but i still dont know what to do

Comment: An entire function that has a polynomial bound is a polynomial by Cauchy applied to large $R$ - if $f=\sum a_mz^m, |f(z)| \le C|z^q|$ then $a_m=0, m > q$

Comment: isnt this just the task in other words? this doesnt help me ....cant you show a start of the proof?

Comment: do you know Cauchy formula to compute $a_n$ or even easier as it does all in one swoop, Parseval formula ($\sum |a_n|^2R^{2n} =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(Re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta\le ||f||_{R}^2 \le C^2R^{2q}$? ; for example the latter implies $|a_m|^2R^{2m} \le C^2R^{2q}$ for all $R >0$ and if now $m>q$ this clearly implies $a_m=0, m>q$